# Javascript decimal rounding problem - precision

Tags: javascript, math, rounding

I've got this function as I'm trying to round up to the next decimal place and I have read a lot of information on this topic, but it doesn't seem to register.

```
function myFunction() {
var testNumber = 399.894;       // required output is 399.90 - correct
var testNumber = 389.894;       // required outout is 389.90 - correct
var testNumber = 389.891;       // required output is 390.90 - correct
var testNumber = 379.791        // required output is 379.80 - correct
var testNumber = 399.991        // required output is 400.00 - correct
var testNumber = 379.761        // required output is 379.77 - incorrect - shows 379.80

return Number(Math.round(testNumber+'e1')+'e-1');
}

var myNumbers = myFunction();
alert(myNumbers );
```

What I thought might be an easy task to make sure it rounds up to the next cent seems to not work properly

Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/axd0y581/5/

hopefully someone here might be able to dumb it down for me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What about trying something like this:

```
return Number(Math.ceil(testNumber * 100)/100).toFixed(2);
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdVYKZ?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

probably you could try this: `Math.ceil(testNumber +'e2')/100`